# Creating a matrix of random data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

I am trying to create a matrix in python that is 30 × 10 and has randomly generated numbers inside of it. But my numbers in the matrix have to follow the condition:

> Randomly generate 30 data points from the sine function, where each data point (x,y) has the form
>
> *x* = [x<sup>0</sup>, x<sup>1</sup>, x<sup>2</sup>,..., x<sup>10</sup>], x ∈ [0, 2π]
>
> *y* = sin(x) + ε, ε ∈ N(0,0.3)

How might I be able to go about this?

Right now I only have a 1 × 10 matrix

```py
def generate_sin_data():

    x = np.random.rand()
    y = np.sin(x)
    features = [x**0, x**1, x**2, x**3, x**4,x**5, x**6, x**7, x**8, x**9,x**10]


    return x,y,features
```

Comment: It seems there are two types of `x` here. Which one do you want in here: `y = sin(x) + ε`?

Comment: You don't have a 1x10 matrix, you have 2 arrays of shapes (1,),  (1,), and a list of length 10.

Comment: There are 11 numbers from `0` to `10` included. Does it mean that you want a 30 x 11 matrix?

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I follow everything, but we can break it down. Here's how you can generate 30 random numbers between 0 and 2π:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random(30) * 2*np.pi
```

Here, `x` is a 1D array of 30 numbers. Check this with `x.shape`.

Now if you add a dimension, it's easy to generate a matrix of powers up to 10 using NumPy's broadcasting feature. The question seems to ask for 11 numbers (0 to 10) not 10, so I'll do that:

```
X = x.reshape(-1, 1) ** np.arange(0, 11)
```

That `reshape` effectively turns `x` into a column vector. Now check `X.shape` and it's `(30, 11)`, which is what I think you were after. Notice we use a big `X` for a matrix — this convention will help you keep track of things. Each column of `X` is the original function raised to a power from 0 to 10. (Note that each column comes from the same set of random numbers — I'm not sure if that's what you want?)

If you want `y` as a function of `x` (the vector) then do like so:

```
ϵ = np.random.random(30) * 0.3
y = np.sin(x) + ϵ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
# 30 random uniform values in [0, 2*pi)
_x = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, 30)

# matrix of 30x10:
x = np.array([
    [v ** i for i in range(10)]
    for v in _x
])

# random 30x10 normal noise:
eps = np.random.normal(0, 0.3, [30, 10])

# final result 30x10 matrix:
y = np.sin(x) + eps
```